Ordered Pairs in CPLEX OPL
I'm trying to model the following in CPLEX:
Image
Here is my attempt, is this correct? I'm note sure if this is correct since the index "i" is used multiple times.
tuple _IU_ {
  int i;
  int t;
};
{_IU_} IU = {<1, 1>, <1, 2>,
             <2, 1>, <2, 2>};

tuple _IC_ {
  int i;
  int c;
};
{_IC_} IC = {<1, 1>, <1, 2>, <1, 3>, <1, 4>};

int NT = 31;

dvar float+ FCTU[1..NI, 1..NU, 1..NC, 1..NT];
dvar float+ FTU[1..NI, 1..NU, 1..NT];

subject to {
 sixteen: forall(<i, u> in IU, t in 1..NT) FTU[i, u, t] == sum(<i, c> in IC) FCTU[i, u, c, t];
};



if you write
execute
{
  thisOplModel.settings.bigmapthreshold=1000000;
  
}

tuple _IU_ {
  int i;
  int t;
};
{_IU_} IU = {<1, 1>, <1, 2>,
             <2, 1>, <2, 2>};

tuple _IC_ {
  int i;
  int c;
};
{_IC_} IC = {<1, 1>, <1, 2>, <1, 3>, <1, 4>};

int NT = 31;
int NI=2;
int NU=3;
int NC=4;

dvar float+ FCTU[1..NI, 1..NU, 1..NC, 1..NT];
dvar float+ FTU[1..NI, 1..NU, 1..NT];

subject to {
 forall(<i, u> in IU, t in 1..NT) 
 sixteen:
 FTU[i, u, t] == sum(<i, c> in IC) FCTU[i, u, c, t];
};

in the IDE you can explore the constraints

